# Flutter SocketIo Client TimeOut

Tags: flutter, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to add socket io to a flutter project. I'm using socket_io_client 2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0 but when I try to connect to server's socket it just refuse the connection and throw a timeout error.

Here's the code im using:

```
 _connectSocket()  {
 Socket socket = io('SERVER IP', 
OptionBuilder()
.enableAutoConnect()
  .build()
);
socket.onConnecting((data) => print("conecting socket..."));
socket.onConnectError((data) => print("error : "+data.toString()));
socket.onConnectTimeout((data) => print(data.toString()));

}
```

Has anyone been through this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
socket = IO.io("ip sever",<String, dynamic>{
    "transports": ["websocket"],
    "autoConnect": false,
    'extraHeaders': {'foo': 'bar'},
  }); socket.connect();
  // socket = await IO.io('ip server',
  //     OptionBuilder()
  //         .setTransports(['websocket']).build());
  socket.onConnect((_) => print('connect'));
  socket.onConnect((_) {
    print('connect');
    
  });
  socket.onConnectError((data) => print( 'error : '+ data.toString() ));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).